# How can I model such count data with underdispersion?

Tags: count-data, change-point, underdispersion

Here is an example of my data:

```
2 6 4 5 2 5 4 4 2 3 3 5 5 6 5 6 **15 19 16 9 
14 14 11 10** 6 4 2
```

In my assumption, the sequence can be separated into regimes, for instance, `2 6 4 5..6 6 5 6` belong to the first regime, and the bold numbers belong to the second one. My work is to detect the shift from one regime to another regime, which is usually called "change-point detection."

My question is: how can I model the data in each regime(or segments). In my understanding, the under-dispersion and zero-truncated properties should be considered. So is there any proper model for my data?

Comment: Please tell us more about your data.  Can they be considered independent? Are they integral? Must they be positive, as "zero-truncated" suggests?  On what basis have you concluded they are underdispersed? What do they measure?  How important is it to avoid detecting spurious changes compared to failing to identify actual changes?

Comment: Yes, right now it is suitable to consider them independent. Yes, they are positive integers (count data).

Comment: Roughly I calculated the mean and sample variance of the data in two regimes (numbers before bold font numbers and bold font numbers), and I found var < mean. Therefore, I am doubting underdispersion exists, but I am not sure if that is correct for undersidpersion is rare. At last, before I get a suitable model for my data, I think it is a little bit confusing for me to answer the importance of avoiding the detection of spurious changes.

Comment: You are simply attempting to detect regime change?  Have you considered a simple solution where you keep a running tally of the sample mean and variance within a moving window, and then report when an observation is detected that exceeds this running mean plus some number of standard deviations?  This is a simple approach, but is used successfully for small embedded systems and sensors.

Comment: Moving window is a method intuitively; however, this is not practical in my question, for that brings too many errors.

Comment: Why not use simple linear discriminate analysis?  Basically, just use Bayes Rule to determine the probability of each observation coming from either regime, and find a single threshold value that separates the regimes. In your data, the value of 10, 9,8, or 7 seems to perfectly classify the data.

Comment: I am using bayesian method now. However, this is just an example, not all my real data. Exactly, for most data, I don't know what the threshold value is, and meanwhile, I am doing an online detecting algorithm. Thus, I think put forward a model and then detect the change of the parameters of the model is the way I need. Thanks.